# mysqlimport - where is the imported data stored?

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

Huge mysql noob. Sorry in advance if this is dumb but I have searched around before posting.

I use mysqlimport on a local file to a mysql database that's running on my computer. If I delete the original file that was imported, can I still access the data? If so, where is the data being stored? On some Oracle server?

If it's stored locally, is it stored in a compressed version that takes up less space on my harddrive?

Thanks,

fertileneutrino

Comment: You said "I use mysqlimport on a local file". And I ask: exactly what command/code have you run?

Answer (score 0):

if you import a file to a database, it is going to store an instance of that data in the database, so yes, you should still be able to access the data, but why would you want to delete it?

It is being stored in a pool of database files in mySQL, they are referenced when you start mysql...yes the imported doc, is just a .dat file in most cases, as your database file.

Comment: So deleting the original file won't clear up any space on my harddrive? It's a 4gb file.

Comment: well if you have a 4gb .dat file, the size is 4gb, your database file is going to be relative... look for a .sql file representing the original, examine the contents and make sure that everything is being brought through. 4GB isn't really that big if working in an enterprise setting. If this is for school or something I see where you would run into an issue during transmission. It will clear the 4GB of the original file, which if you have a .sql file and a .dat file the combined is 8GB, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

When you import the data it is stored in database files on your local machine, using the mysql client program or something like phpmyadmin you should be able to view your imported data.

It's no longer stored in the same format as it was when you first imported it.

you can use something like mysqldump to get the data back out.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html